# Animating a clipPath from onDraw

Tags: android, animation, kotlin, android-canvas, ondraw

I am drawing a custom shape in onDraw with `Paint` and `Canvas`. Within the onDraw class, I have a rectangle `clipPath`.

I Would like to be able to animate the position (animate from left-to-right) of the `clipPath` from `MainActivity`. This will hide the shape that's drawn (BlackGraph) from left to right.

```
class BlackGraph(context: Context) : View(context) {

    var clipAmount:Float = 0.0f

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        val paint = Paint()
        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        paint.color = Color.parseColor("#000000")
        val path = Path()

        val clipPath = Path()
        clipPath.addRect(clipAmount, 0f, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat(), Path.Direction.CW)
        canvas.clipPath(clipPath)

        path.moveTo(0f, height-30.toFloat())
        path.lineTo(width.toFloat(), 0f)
        path.lineTo(width.toFloat(), height.toFloat())
        path.lineTo(0f, height.toFloat())
        path.lineTo(0f, 0f)

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint)

    }
}
```

In **onCreate**:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val layout1 = findViewById<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>(R.id.layout1)
    val blackGraph = BlackGraph(this)

    layout1.addView(blackGraph)

    val valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 450f)
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener {
        val value = it.animatedValue as Float
        println("Value -> $value")
        blackGraph.clipAmount = value
    }
    valueAnimator.duration = 2000
    valueAnimator.start()

}
```

I am trying to simply animate the position of clipAmount to achieve the desired animation.

The problem is in `onCreate`, the clipAmount value never animated. The print statement works just fine, however. Logcat is full of float values ranging from 0.0 to 450.0

How can I animate the movement of the `clipPath`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you got some problems here. The first, you shouldn't init Paint, Path in onDraw(), it should be initialized first and you can modify it later and you will get better performance. When you update `clipAmount` value, you need to call `postInvalidateOnAnimation()` to make your `BlackGraph` view to draw again, this will trigger the method `onDraw()`. The last thing is `clipPath` need to call `reset()` to clear before add new path with the method `addRect()`.

```
class BlackGraph(context: Context) : View(context) {

    var clipAmount:Float = 0.0f
    val paint = Paint().apply {
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
        color = Color.parseColor("#000000")
    }
    val path = Path()
    val clipPath = Path()

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        clipPath.apply {
            reset()
            addRect(clipAmount, 0f, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat(), Path.Direction.CW)
        }
        canvas.clipPath(clipPath)

        path.moveTo(0f, height-30.toFloat())
        path.lineTo(width.toFloat(), 0f)
        path.lineTo(width.toFloat(), height.toFloat())
        path.lineTo(0f, height.toFloat())
        path.lineTo(0f, 0f)

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
    }

    fun animateClipAmount() {
        val valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 450f)
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener {
            val value = it.animatedValue as Float
            clipAmount = value
            println("Value -> $clipAmount")
            postInvalidateOnAnimation()
        }
        valueAnimator.duration = 2000
        valueAnimator.start()
    }

}
```

In onCreate:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val layout1 = findViewById<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>(R.id.layout1)

        val blackGraph = BlackGraph(this)
        layout1 .addView(blackGraph)
        blackGraph.animateClipAmount()
    }

}
```